# can some 1 point out the null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have edited the code and now the null pointer error is pointing inside the for loop their are less errors than before but i still dont't know why a nullpointer is called.

```
 public class searchlist extends ListActivity 
 {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new loadSomeStuff().execute();
}

public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]>
{
  ProgressDialog dialog;

  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
     dialog = new ProgressDialog(searchlist.this); 
     dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
     dialog.setMax(100);
     dialog.show();
  }
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(int i =0; i<20; i++)
        {
          publishProgress(5);
          try
          {
          Thread.sleep(80);
          } catch(InterruptedException e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        int loops = search_page.returnlooped();
        int[] teacup = search_page.returnNumArray();
        sqlStuff searching = new sqlStuff(searchlist.this);
        String[] IDSysNames = searching.getIDSysName();
        searching.close();

        String[] resultList = new String[loops];
        for(int i=0; i < loops; i++ )
        {
            if(IDSysNames[teacup[i]] != null)
            {

            resultList[i].equals(IDSysNames[teacup[i]]);

            }
        }
         setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(searchlist.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultList));
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress)
    {
        dialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
    }
}





@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
     //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //String Pos = resultList[position];

    Intent ourIntent = new Intent("com.MC.ChemPal.RESULT2");
    startActivity(ourIntent);
}
}
```

The method used within the code above is below .

```
public String[] getIDSysName()
{
    String[] result = new String[0];

    try
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_SYSNAME};
        Cursor c  =  ChemPal.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        Log.d("SqlDStuff", "Cursor count: "+c.getCount());
        int iSysName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SYSNAME);

        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }

        result = new String[i];
        i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result[i] = c.getString(iSysName);
            i++;

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: show those methods here.. also the logcat error data

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, you are initializing your members when instantiating your Activity. This means you are calling `String[] SysNames = useSystname();` and in the end calling `sqlStuff searching = new sqlStuff(this);`. I suspect that "this" is not yet fully created when it is refferencing to itself.
Does the problem occur when you do `String[] SysNames = useSystname();` in onCreate ?

Comment: I tried doing it in a later class but still no luck same error so i'm guessing its not a time issue.

Comment: edited the code now getting null pointer in different location  now its in the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this

```
int loops = search_page.returnlooped();
int[] teacup = search_page.returnNumArray();
```

before `onCreate()`, because you're trying to access application resources that are still not initialized (hence the NPEs). As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), you cannot assume the activity is launched until `onCreate()` is called.

> The entire lifetime of an activity happens between the first call to
>   onCreate(Bundle) through to a single final call to onDestroy().

As a general rule: you shouldn't do *anything* before `onCreate()` is called.

Also you should not do DB reading in `onCreate()` because this is run by the UI thread, and you might get an ANR if DB access is too long. See [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do tasks on the background (you might think about a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) when loading data if your GUI needs that data right away).

Comment: i have moved most of it into an async class after oncreate and their are less errors but still errors the error is still pointing in the for loop at the statement.   resultList[i].equals(SysNames[teacup[i]]);

Comment: You have too many errors in your code. I strongly suggest you read a good tutorial about Java arrays (and about Java in general).